# Why is 'shift + space' not popularly used?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, space-bar

Why isn't <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> popularly utilised?
Chrome uses <kbd>space</kbd> as "page down", and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> as "page up". However, I haven't been able to find a single occurrence of it being utilised during typing.

As a programmer, having it assigned to `underscore` (which is often used in variable names to represent spaces) makes sense.
Assigning it to <kbd>tab</kbd> for a regular user might even make sense (it's *KIND OF* an alternative space) which would open up the tab key for a different utility.

Comment: if it would be convenient for you, you can always make a hotkey for it with AutoHotkey.

Comment: I sense a question for why '_' in variables is horrible UX could be made...

Comment: Shift + space while typing gives you taller spaces.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**It's not used because of unintended consequences.**

If I'm typing something and want to write THE END, remembering to let go of Shift in the middle or after each word becomes a huge burden. Even understanding **why** the computer didn't type the letters I wanted is confusing.

In the case of Chrome the space bar isn't being used for the " " character, but as a directional key (like the arrow keys). In that case using shift + space makes some conceptual sense to reverse the direction.

You may be able to make a decent argument for shift + space being used for _ in programming IDE's, as there is likely less need to type in all caps. Even then, it would have to be an option that could be disabled as required by the language being used.

Comment: If you're writing all caps, then Shift could ignore that - just like Caps + - is still - and not _.

Answer (score 0):

It could be confusing to users to have something like an underscore bound to the spacebar since that would require adding more words/symbols to the key. Most keyboards either just have the word "[space]" written on it, or nothing at all. People learning to use computers don't need a key so commonly used to be made more complicated (think about how strange it would be to someone learning to use a computer to see "[space]/_")

Advanced users, such as yourself, can figure out how to hotkey the underscore to the spacebar so it isn't too much fo a problem anyways.

I would guess that there is also a chance that once someone is holding the shift key, they could quite easily hit the space bar when going for any of the bottom row of keys on a QWERTY keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Within many Microsoft products (particularly excel and SQL Server) if you hold shift and press the space bar after clicking in a cell it will highlight the entire row of the cell you clicked on. This comes in very handy when you want to track across a very wide table.